# Update one filter in GPUImageFilterGroup without redraw all filters

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I use *GPUImageFilterGroup* to apply some filters to a image. All **filters** **stable** (all parameters is constant), but **last** **filter** is **variable** (some parameter is changed).

I need redraw image after last filter was changed.

Now I call processImage on source *GPUImagePicture*, but this invocation redraw all filters and speed is too slow.

How can I redraw only last filter in the group?

I think, I should save copy of a frame buffer before last filter will draw, and when I've change some parameter in the last filter, I  should use saved frame buffer to redraw last filter. But I can't find how I can save copy of the frame buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this, by subclassing GPUImageFilter and GPUImageFilterGroup.
In GPUImageFilter I've overloaded method

```
- (void)newFrameReadyAtTime:(CMTime)frameTime atIndex:(NSInteger)textureIndex
<...>

[self renderToTextureWithVertices:imageVertices textureCoordinates:[[self class] textureCoordinatesForRotation:inputRotation]];
_bufferCallback(self);
[self informTargetsAboutNewFrameAtTime:frameTime];
<...>
```

In GPUImageFilterGroup I've overloaded methods:

```
- (void)addFilter:(GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *)newFilter
{
    NSParameterAssert([newFilter isKindOfClass:    [FAEShiftFilterWithBackOutputBuffer class]]);
    if ([newFilter isKindOfClass:[FAEShiftFilterWithBackOutputBuffer class]])
    {
        __weak typeof(self) selfWeak = self;
        [(FAEShiftFilterWithBackOutputBuffer*)newFilter setOutputBufferCallback:^(FAEShiftFilterWithBackOutputBuffer *sender) {
        __strong typeof(selfWeak) selfStrong = selfWeak;
        if (selfStrong)
        {
            if (!selfStrong.lastFramebuffer)
            {
                if ([selfStrong isPreLastFilter:sender])
                {
                    selfStrong.lastFramebuffer = [sender framebufferForOutput];
                    [selfStrong.lastFramebuffer lock];
                }
            }
        }
    }];
}
[super addFilter:newFilter];
}
```

This method stores outputFrameBuffer from preLast filter.
And method:

```
- (void)newFrameReadyAtTime:(CMTime)frameTime atIndex:(NSInteger)textureIndex
{
    if (self.filterCount > 1)
   {
    if (self.lastFramebuffer)
    {
        GPUImageFilter* lastFilter = (GPUImageFilter*)self.terminalFilter;
        [lastFilter setInputFramebuffer:self.lastFramebuffer atIndex:0];
        [lastFilter newFrameReadyAtTime:frameTime atIndex:textureIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        [super newFrameReadyAtTime:frameTime atIndex:textureIndex];
    }
}
else
{
    [super newFrameReadyAtTime:frameTime atIndex:textureIndex];
}
}
```

Also I reset saved framebuffer in dealloc and forceProcessingAtSize and forceProcessingAtSizeRespectingAspectRatio methods.

```
- (void)_clearLastFrameBuffer
{
 if (_lastFramebuffer)
 {
     [_lastFramebuffer unlock];
     _lastFramebuffer = nil;
 }
}
```